# Big Curly braces in Latex with

Tags: delimiters

I am trying to get the equation below to display a big curly braces with 4 conditional equations but my latex is giving me error 'File not found'.

```
 \documentclass{article}   
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{equation}
   H^'(\theta)_{mn}=
   \begin{cases}
    \frac{x_i-x_j}{d_{ij}}, & \text{if \theta_n = x_i}.\\
    \frac{x_j-x_i}{d_{ij}}, & \text{if \theta_n = x_j}.\\
    \frac{y_i-y_j}{d_{ij}}, & \text{if \theta_n = y_i}.\\
    \frac{y_j-y_i}{d_{ij}}, & \text{if \theta_n = y_j}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What errors you're getting? Also, add a compilable code so people can run it with less effort.

Comment: I get the error 'File not found'

Comment: Have you saved the file you are trying to compile?

Comment: You also have maths inside the \text commands argument.

Comment: yes i have saved the file. There is also maths in the argument

Comment: `\text{if \theta_n = y_j}` is wrong, it should be `\text{if $\theta_n = y_j$}` as the equation part needs math mode and `\text` sends you to text mode.

Comment: Also, it should be `H'`, not `H^'`.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
H'(\theta)_{mn}=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{x_i-x_j}{d_{ij}}, & \text{if $\theta_n = x_i$}.\\
 \frac{x_j-x_i}{d_{ij}}, & \text{if $\theta_n = x_j$}.\\
 \frac{y_i-y_j}{d_{ij}}, & \text{if $\theta_n = y_i$}.\\
 \frac{y_j-y_i}{d_{ij}}, & \text{if $\theta_n = y_j$}.\\
 0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}` should correctly compile (catching the maths in text mode, correcting `H^'` and adding `\begin{document}`) does this compile for you?

Comment: You should get the error `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.` not file not found. Are you sure you get a file error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple errors (e.g., no `\begin{document}`, `H^'` and maths inside `\text` command arguments) and a style issue. Here's one that works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
   H'(\theta)_{mn}=
   \begin{cases}
    (x_i-x_j)/d_{ij}, & \text{if } \theta_n = x_i.\\
    (x_j-x_i)/d_{ij}, & \text{if } \theta_n = x_j.\\
    (y_i-y_j)/d_{ij}, & \text{if } \theta_n = y_i.\\
    (y_j-y_i)/d_{ij}, & \text{if } \theta_n = y_j.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
   \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To make a whole code block display as a block, rather than using backtick delimiters, highlight the block and click on the `{}` icon atop the edit box.  Internally, it indents those lines 4 spaces, but what is displayed is the block displayed in code form.  I edited your answer to do this.

Comment: The backticks are useful for displaying a short **inline** code sentence.